# JQuery Ajax with back button

Tags: jquery

How do I handle navigation with Jquery Ajax?

For eg. I have a home page. 2 ajax link that loads the content of either `page1` and `page2`.

I'd like the url to be: `localhost/page1` or `localhost/page2`. I know this is possible but I do not know the name of this feature.

Coded examples would be nice.

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="page1">Page 1</a> | <a href="page2">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div id="Container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just guesing if you are looking for some thiing like this

```
$("#nav>a").click(function(e){
 $.get($(this).attr("href"),function(data){
  $("#Container").html(data);
 });
 return false;
});
```

Comment: It's not clear in the OP, but from the title they seem to want back button function.  AFAIK this code won't return the container to its previous state on hitting the back button.  Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `window.location` value to reflect your page changes.

Once you know your page you can do something like this:

```
var location = window.location.toString();
var pageHash = "#" + page;

if (window.location.hash == "") {
    window.location = location + pageHash;
}
else {
    window.location = location.substring(0, location.indexOf("#")) + pageHash;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed the hash, I'd like it to look like a url.

Comment: Where would I put the ajax call to retrieve the content?

Comment: removing the # is not ajax, you'll just be navigating to another page

Comment: I would wire up a click event on the for `<a>` tags within `#nav`